# Laravel 7 migration file from existing model

Tags: model, migration, laravel-7

How can I create migration file from existing model in Laravel 7, I've tried using Xethron - Laravel Migration Generator but it's cannot running in laravel 7

Comment: can you try to be more specific? What does it means "it's cannot running"  ?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved that problem yesterday night ; there is a magic tool I found :

```
[https://github.com/oscarafdev/migrations-generator][1]
```

As soon as you add the depency you'll be able to generate all your existing schema and turn it into your mogrations (vice-verca) . Enjoy !

It's work for laravel 5 and higher versions I'm presently using laravel 7 (latest stable ) version